# ERROR:java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, runtimeexception

hi everyone i'm trying to get the user's location, but when i ask for permissions google maps doesn't load. Specifically I have this error:

```
2022-07-03 12:46:39.032 12031-12031/com.example.progetto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.progetto, PID: 12031
    java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bj.J(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413068@22.24.13 (100700-0):10)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.ba(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413068@22.24.13 (100700-0):172)
        at et.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413068@22.24.13 (100700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.setMyLocationEnabled(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
        at com.example.progetto.MapsLine.onMapReady(MapsLine.java:207)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzat.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:3)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
        at es.bc(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413068@22.24.13 (100700-0):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413068@22.24.13 (100700-0):1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

My code is:

```
public class MapsLine extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
        private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
        private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
        private LocationCallback locationCallback;
        private boolean requestingLocationUpdates = true;
        GoogleMap gMap;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps_line, container, false);
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                        getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate");
                fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
                //callback per gli aggiornamenti di posizione
                locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                if (locationResult == null) {
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", "location request is null");
                                        return;
                                }
                                //aggiorno i dati nelle textView con le informazioni della posizione aggiornata
                                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                                        Log.d("Location", "New Location received: " + location.toString());
                                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", String.valueOf(latitude));
                                        Log.d("main_activiyt_maps", String.valueOf(longitude));
                                }
                        }
                };
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                requestingLocationUpdates = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onResume");
                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Permessi OK");
                        //richiedo l'ultima posizione
                        //richiedo aggiornamenti sulla posizione
                        startLocationUpdates();
                }
        }
        public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //ho i permessi, scrivo nella casella di testo che va tutto bene
                        Log.d("Location", "The permission is granted");
                        return true;
                } else {
                        //non ho i permessi, devo richiederli
                        Log.d("Location", "Ask for permission");

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                        return false;
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        // permission was granted
                                        Log.d("Location", "Now the permission is granted");
                                        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
                                } else {
                                        // permission was not granted
                                        Log.d("Location", "Permission still not granted");
                                }
                                break;
                        }
        }
}
        public void getLastKnownLocation() {
                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                                                if (location != null) {
                                                        Log.d("Location", "Last known location:" + location.toString());
                                                } else {
                                                        Log.d("Location", "Last Known location not available");
                                                }
                                        }
                                });
                }
        }

        //per chiedere la posizione aggiornata
        private void startLocationUpdates() {
                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                        requestingLocationUpdates = true;
                        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); //in ms.
                        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());

                }
        }
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                gMap = googleMap;
                gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                gMap.clear(); //clear old markers
        }
}
```

My themanifest code is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_key" ></meta-data>
```

in the manifest I have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and in the code I check the permissions(checkLocationPermission()). why does it crash at the first start, when the app asks me for permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onViewCreated()`, you are setting up your `SupportMapFragment`. In `onMapReady()`, you are trying to use location information via `gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`. Do not call `setMyLocationEnabled()` until the user grants you permission.

Comment: thanks a lot now i solved but one question, the onMapReady method when called? Is onMapReady called after the user has given permissions?

Comment: @Elly: "is onMapReady called after the user has given permissions?" -- no. It is called sometime after you call `supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`.